# хочу чтоб при нажатии на <td> внизу появился только одна таблица где будет только <td> на который я нажал..посмотрите код пожалуйста

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Obj onclick</title>
    <style>
        td,th{
            border:1px solid gray;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script >
    request();
function request() {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('Get', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onload = () => getResponse(xhr);

}


function getResponse(xhr) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        let response = JSON.parse(xhr.response);

        if (Array.isArray(response)) {
            table(response);
        }
    }
}

let arr = [];
let arr1 = [];
function table(data) {
    let table = document.createElement('table');
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    let thKeyNames = data[0];
    for (let key in thKeyNames) {
        if (key !== 'company' && key !== 'address') {
            let th = document.createElement('th');

            th.innerHTML = key.toUpperCase();
            arr.push(key.toUpperCase());
            tr.append(th);
        }
        table.append(tr);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.addEventListener('click', newPerson);

        for (let users in data[i]) {
            if (users !== 'company' && users !== 'address') {
                let td = document.createElement('td');
                arr1.push(data[i][users])
                
                td.innerHTML = data[i][users];
                tr.append(td);
            }
            table.append(tr);
        }
     

    }
    document.body.append(table);
}
function newPerson(event) {
    let tr = [...event.target.parentElement.children].map(td => td.innerText);
    let table = document.createElement('table'); 
    let newTr = document.createElement('tr');
    let newTr2 = document.createElement('tr');
    table.setAttribute("class", "keyPerson");
    let keyPerson = document.getElementsByClassName('keyPerson');
    

  

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let th = document.createElement('th');

        th.innerHTML = arr[i];
        newTr.append(th);
    }
    table.append(newTr);
    for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
       let td = document.createElement('td');

       td.innerHTML = tr[i];
       newTr2.append(td);
    
 
   }
   table.append(newTr2);


    
   document.body.append(table);



}
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('keyPerson')[1]) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('keyPerson')[0].remove()
   }
```